# C# How to identify unknown user email address in SmtpClient.Send()

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailmessage

I am using the following code to send emails internally at my company on our own relay server:

```
using (MailMessage em = new MailMessage()) {

    em.From = new MailAddress("noreply@mycompany.com", "From Me");
    em.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    em.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try {
        em.To.Add(new MailAddress("Addy_1@mycompany.com"));
        em.To.Add(new MailAddress("Addy_2@mycompany.com"));
        :
        :
        em.To.Add(new MailAddress("Addy_99@mycompany.com"));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.Write(e);
    }

    em.Subject = "My Subject";
    em.Body = "Email body";
}

using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()) {

    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Host = "smtprelay.mycompany.com";

        smtp.Send(em);
    }

}
```

If any of the emails are no longer valid, nothing is reported until you actually attempt to .send() the email, by which time it is too late, and you end up with:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.1.1 User unknown
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at SendEmail.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\SendEmail.ashx:line 104
```

Is there any way to perform this email validation before hand?  `.To.Add()` doesn't seem to raise any alert.  Or, once it fails, is there any way to determine WHICH email address was the one that was bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to try/catch the Send method and catch either SmtpFailedRecipientsException or SmtpFailedRecipientException

[SmtpFailedRecipient**s**Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception?view=netcore-3.1)

[SmtpFailedRecipientException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception?view=netcore-3.1)

There's a FailedRecipient property for the singular recipient exception:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception.failedrecipient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks.  I will be back on that project in the morning tomorrow, and will give it a shot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  So, It looks like I am right at least that you cannot test an email address before sending it (which makes sense, really), but I see now that I can at least determine which email was bad.  Thanks.  I will mark this as the answer.  Again, thank you for the direction.